# Complete the proof of $a(-b) = -(ab)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

Prove $a(-b)=-(ab)$, using axioms of equality, addition, and multiplication.

I have tried: Let $a$ and $b$ be integers.

$(-a)+a= 0$ by the inverse axiom

$a=-(-a)$ by (If $a=b$ and $c=d$ then $a+c=b+d$ and $ac=bd$)

$a(-b)=-(-a)(-b)$ by (If $a=b$ and $c=d$ then $a+c=b+d$ and $ac=bd$)

$a(-b)=-(ab)$ by associative axiom.

End of proof.

Not quite certain if I did this correctly, I think I may have done some steps without an axiom to prove the step. I also, think I may have done some 'illegal' steps that don't actually fit with the amxioms I chose.

Comment: You can't assume that $-x = (-1)x$ before proving it.

Comment: By the distributive law: 
$$a(-b)+ab=a(-b+b)=0$$
and so by uniqueness of the additive inverse, $a(-b)=-ab$.

Comment: @uniquesolution: you should enter that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how $a=-(-a)$ follows from the fact that addition and multiplication are operations (that is, from the fact that $a+b=c+d$ and $ab=cd$ whenever $a=c$ and $b=d$). Rather, this follows from the definition of additive inverses, since $-(-a)$ is the unique number $c$ such that $-a+c=0,$ and clearly, $-a+a=0$ by (commutativity and by) definition of $-a.$

I also can't see how you've used the associative axiom, here, so your conclusion that $-(-a)(-b)=-(a\cdot b)$ has not been justified.

Remember that, axiomatically, $-(a\cdot b)$ is the unique number $c$ such that $a\cdot b+c=0.$ So, what you're being asked to show is that $a\cdot b+a\cdot(-b)=0.$ Readily, $$a\cdot b+a\cdot(-b)=a\cdot(b+-b)=a\cdot 0$$ by distributivity and additive inverses. If you've already proved (or taken as an axiom) that $a\cdot 0$ is necessarily $0,$ then you're done. Otherwise, all that remains is to show that $a\cdot 0=0$ for all $a.$ We can get started on this as follows: $$a\cdot 0=0+a\cdot 0=-a+a+a\cdot0=-a+a\cdot1+a\cdot0$$

Can you see the axioms we've used so far? Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

The intended method is to use the additive inverse property: $-x=(-1)x$.

\begin{align*}
a(-b)&=a((-1)b)&\quad\text{Additive Inverse Property}\\ 
&=a(b(-1))&\quad\text{Commutativity}\\
&=(ab)(-1)&\quad\text{Associativity}\\
&=(-1)(ab)&\quad\text{Commutativity}\\
&=-(ab)&\quad\text{Additive Inverse Property}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: That's not the definition of negation though

Comment: I meant, additive inverse property. Fixing.

Comment: This definition of negation actually follows from the OP's more general result (in the special case that $b=1$), so I suspect it isn't given to the OP in that way. I could be wrong, though.